# Power BI query error : Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near ';'. Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

The following runs well in SSMS. However in Power BI, I am getting this error and do not know why:

> Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near ';'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Database = AdventureWorks

Query is:

```
;WITH Totals AS
(
    SELECT 
        ProductCategoryID, COUNT(*) AS TotalProducts 
    FROM 
        SalesLT.Product
    GROUP BY 
        ProductCategoryID
),
Flat AS 
(
    SELECT 
        PC.ParentProductCategoryID, PC.ProductCategoryID,
        PC.[Name], Totals.TotalProducts
    FROM 
        SalesLT.ProductCategory PC 
    INNER JOIN 
        Totals ON (PC.ProductCategoryID = Totals.ProductCategoryID)
),
Grand AS
(
    SELECT 
        Flat.ParentProductCategoryID, 
        SUM(Flat.TotalProducts) AS [GrandTotal]
    FROM 
        Flat 
    GROUP BY 
        Flat.ParentProductCategoryID
)
SELECT 
    Grand.ParentProductCategoryID, Grand.GrandTotal, PC.[Name]
FROM 
    Grand 
INNER JOIN 
    SalesLT.ProductCategory PC ON (Grand.ParentProductCategoryID = PC.ProductCategoryID);
```